# What to do? After trying to update Android Studio it doesn't want to startup anymore

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, plugins

I tried to update Android Studio from 2.1.2 to 2.2.x
After downloading patches AS tried to perform patch but this wouldn't succeed and since then I can't seem to get Android Studio started anymore.
Apparently something went wrong with pluginManager, but so far I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Errormessage after I select a project i want to open at startup AS:

Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com/android/builder/model/BaseArtifact [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android]

Comment: Delete `.android` directory from users home directory. This will delete AS cache. After that try to open Android Studio. The `.android` directory will be created automatically.

Comment: i have same error
Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: com/android/builder/model/BaseArtifact [Plugin: org.jetbrains.android